# Merge two inequality togehter

Tags: inequality

There are two inequalities
$A+x\leq1$ , $0<x<1$ how can I merge them into one inequality in terms of $A$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All we can have is 
$$A\lt 1$$
because
$$A\le 1-x\ \ \text{and}\ \ 0\lt 1-x\lt 1.$$

Comment: can't we have other interpretation due to $0<1-x$

Comment: @EKH: No, we can't. All we can say is $A\lt 1$.

Comment: does it mean that $A<1$ is  not a complete answer? because we don't care about the constraint $0<1-x$

Comment: @EKH: What I meant is that $A+x\le 1,0\lt x\lt 1\Rightarrow A\lt 1$. We can't have an equivalent condition about only $A$.